# Как развернуть бота телеграмм?

Tags: c#, telegram

Сделал телеграмм бота по вебинару https://geekbrains.ru/events/781. С компьютера он работает хорошо, но хотелось бы развернуть его на хостинге или на подобном сервисе. Подскажите как.

Comment: Выбрать хостинг, развернуть бота. Вопрос слишком общий, здесь такие закрывают. Что именно вам непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

- Можно использовать любой VPS/VDS-сервер c Linux.
- Можно развернуть бота на Heroku.com или аналогичной платформе